# Firebase Functions - Log outputting lots of extra info after NodeJS upgrade

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just upgraded my Cloud Functions from Node 8 to 10, and it's now outputting a lot of extraneous information that makes looking through my logs more difficult. Is there a way to disable outputting all this extra information?

**createLifetimeMembershipCallable** (Cloud Function)

```
exports.createLifetimeMembershipCallable = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    console.log('                                                  ');
    console.log('--------------------------------------------------');
    console.log('Running createLifetimeMembershipCallable() from js');

    console.log('data.token: ');
    console.log(data.token);
    console.log('data.token.card.id: ');
    console.log(data.token.card.id);
    console.log('data.chargeAmount: ');
    console.log(data.chargeAmount);
    console.log('data.userObj.customerID: ' + data.userObj.customerID);
    console.log('data.userObj.email: ' + data.userObj.email);

    return stripe.charges.create({
        amount: data.chargeAmount,
        currency: 'usd',
        description: 'QuizMeNot Lifetime Membership',
        metadata: data.userObj,
        receipt_email: data.userObj.email,
        source: data.token.id,
        statement_descriptor: 'Membership'
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log('Finished creating charge. Result:');
        console.log(result);

        //Go to user and change membershipTier
        return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(data.userObj.uid).update({
            membershipTier: 'premium',
            purchPlan: 'lifetime',
            token: ''
        });

    });

});
```

**Messy Firebase Functions Log Output:** ([Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIfMW.jpg))

**Messy Firebase Functions Log Output:** ([Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/zAeNt88Y))

[image]

Comment: If the logs come from your code, you might have to just change your code.  Could you edit the question to show a sample of it that generates the output you're already showing?

Comment: I edited the post to include the code I'm using and the outputted logs (in both text and image formats). There are just a couple logs in my code at the top, not nearly *that* many. Other than that it's just a straightforward Stripe charge. Nothing special going on here. It was logging as expected before the Node update.

Comment: What if you eliminate all logging from your code?  Does it still log all that? Can you track it down to perhaps a line of your logs that's getting unexpectedly expanded?

Comment: Ok I think I know what's happening. The Node 8 code showed objects as collapsed by default, which you could expand just by clicking on them. It seems that the Node 10 code is showing all properties of all objects on their own line. They can't be collapsed. The Firebase Functions log shows functions that are updated, and it shows them in collapsed (expandable on click) format. But the functions aren't playing well with the .log(), which is making debugging the server code a nightmare.

Comment: Please feel free to report this to Firebase support in case something is wrong with the console.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Ok, I sent a report, thanks.

Comment: I got a reply from support, saying "_To isolate if this is a Firebase console issue, could you try logging using Node v10 separately from your Functions and see how console.log renders logs?_" I explained that I've never used Node outside of Firebase Functions and would need some guidance on how to do that, but that advice would be out of scope for them to provide me with. Could you guide me on how to log using Node separately from Firebase Functions?